# Laravel looks to insert records in a table that does not exists

Tags: php, mysql, model, laravel-9

It's since two days that I'm trying to solve an issue that i face when i try to insert a record in the DB.

I'm building a project where an admin can create a list of places to visit for users.

I have created 3 tables and relative models as follow : places , place_categories, category_places (this the pivot table).

`places` table has the following inside :

```
 Schema::create('places', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('google_place_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('property_id');
            $table->foreign('property_id')->references('id')->on('properties');
        });
```

And the `Place` model has the following :

```
protected $fillable = [
        'google_place_id',
        'property_id'
    ];

    public function property(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Property::class);
    }

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(PlaceCategory::class);
    }
```

The `place_categories` table has the following code :

```
 Schema::create('place_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

the `PlaceCategory` model has the following :

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function place(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Place::class);
    }
```

While the pivot `category_places` table has the following :

```
 Schema::create('category__places', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('place_id');
            $table->foreign('place_id')->references('id')->on('places');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('place_categories');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And the `Category_Place` has the following code :

```
   protected $table = 'category_places';

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_id', 
        'place_id',
    ];
}
```

In my `PlaceController`, in the `store` method i wrote the following :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $googlePlaceId = $request->input('google_place_id');
        $propertyId= $request->input('property_id');
        $categories= $request->input('categories');
        

        $place = Place::create([
            'google_place_id' => $googlePlaceId,
            'property_id'=> $propertyId,
        ]);

        $place->category()->attach($categories);

        return redirect()->route('home', ['property'=> $propertyId])->with('message', 'Place correctly created');
    }
```

Now, when i try to insert a new place with relative categories i keep getting the following error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myhosthtl.place_place_category' doesn't exist
insert into `place_place_category` (`place_category_id`, `place_id`) values (1, 3)
```

So he's looking for a table called place_place_category that obviously does not exist, but where do he get this table from? I have also declared the `protected $table` in my `Category_Place` model.

After debugging a bit the code, i found out the the error i thrown at line 63 in the `store` method at this line :

```
  $place->category()->attach($categories);
```

It seem like he cant find the place_categories table, but he should insert in the category_places the record for the pivot, not in the places_categories.

Is there anybody able to help me? What Am i doing wrong?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: There's a lot wrong here; you should have 2 Models, `Place` and `Category`, with 3 tables; `places`, `categories` and `place_category`. This would be the "standard" `many-to-many` convention, and you'd define the relationship as Place.php: `public function categories() { return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class); }`, and `Category.php`: `public function places() { return $this->belongsToMany(Place::class); }` and it would just work. If you're going to mess with naming conventions, that fine, see the Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure

Comment: @TimLewis thank you very much for your reply, unfortunately i cannot name it category as i also have another `restaurant_categories` table that is related to restaurants. If i do as you said, should i store the related categories id in the `places` table as an array and simply retrieve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Check the documentation; if you're using non-standard naming, then you need to simply add more to `belongsToMany()`, since it allows up to 4 arguments: `return $this->belongsToMany(Model::class, 'table_name', 'local_id', 'foreign_id');`. And no, array of IDs in a column is bad practice and not normalized data, both of which you should avoid

Comment: @TimLewis I have checked already the documentation but i think i'm missing something and i'm not understanding it properly.  If you could help me to understand, i would really appreciate it. Since the place belongsToMany categories, how i can retrieve all the categories associated to that place without a pivot table? Thank you so much.

Comment: You still have a Pivot Table, I never said to remove it. You just need to pass the correct arguments to `belongsToMany()`. Again, **please read the documentation**. The 2nd argument to `belongsToMany()` is the table name. **You're not passing anything**, so Laravel is guessing it should be `place_place_category`, but you named your table `category__places`, so just use it properly: `belongsToMany(Place::class, 'category__places');` and `belongsToMany(PlaceCategory::class, 'category__places');`.

Comment: No problem   When possible, try to follow Laravel conventions for table and Model naming, which allows Laravel functions like `belongsToMany()` to work with just the 1st argument. But if not possible, remember that Laravel does allow this; you just need to check the Docs to see _how_ it allows it. Also, look into a Polymorphic relationship between Restaurants and Categories, and Products and Categories; you shouldn't need multiple `thing_categories` tables when one would work for both 